# Fancy Box pass textBox value back to parent

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Im having some problems passing the values back to the parent window using the beforeClose parameter.
Currently i have the following:

```
`$(document).ready(function () {
                $("#batch").change(function () {
                    if ($("#batch").prop("checked")) {
                        $.fancybox({
                            'type': 'iframe',
                            'height': 400,
                            'width': 800,
                            'maxWidth': 800,
                            'maxHeight': 400,
                            'href': 'bulkAdd',
                            'beforeClose': function () {
                                var serial = $("#fancybox-frame").contents().find('div#centerDiv');
                                alert(serial.html());
                            }
                        });

                    }
                });
            });`
```

But no matter what i have in the find() field it never finds. When i use firebug to check the HTML generated the ID looks something more like fancybox-frame423104808085. Not sure if thats the reason, but the number sequence is random. Anyone have it working on version 2?

thanks andy

**EDIT** I got it to work using the following

```
 `$(".fancybox-iframe").contents().find("input#txtArea");`
```

Hope that helps someone out

Comment: var serial = $("#fancybox-frame").find('#centerDiv'); Don't use .contents(); because contents is for building a constructor from a collection of objects.